# How can I correct faulty $MANPATH(environment variable)?

Tags: command-line, manpage

My manpath seems to direct itself to the wrong file. when I call `echo $MANPATH` I get this output:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man
```

and when I try to use man pages for anything like ls or man itself, I get the below error:

```
No manual entry for ls
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset `MANPATH`, thusly:

```
MANPATH="" man man
```

Read `man man` to find out the default `MANPATH`.

Edit your `~/.bashrc` (or wherever you set `MANPATH`) to specify the default `MANPATH` explicitly, plus `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man`.

`MANPATH` is a colon-separated list of directories `man` should search, in order. If you add `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man` to the beginning of `MANPATH`, it will shadow the system `man` pages where the names overlap. If you add it at the end of `MANPATH`, the system's `man` pages will be preferred, again, only if the names overlap (if they both have, for example `ls.1`, the first in `MANPATH` will be used).

Comment: Thank you I opened `~/.bashrc` and added `/usr/share/man:` to the manpath now it works and it looks like this: `export MANPATH=/usr/share/man:/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man`

Answer (score 0):

To restore the normal working of `man`, correct where you have set your `MANPATH` variable such that there is a colon at the start or at the end, e.g.

```
MANPATH=":/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man"
```

This way, the value of the variable will be appended to the default list of paths that is searched (or prepended, or inserted between custom paths).